# Strange public note on FBI's silk road address

Tags: transactions, blockchain

http://blockchain.info/tx/532bef49b54304eb2471008d9612ebc6501c91080888a9ba8dd24904d67f19ce

> A deep well lies hidden at 19FZMqGmkLVNxtkjeXW5sUtVThPkFVkThM where
>   strange eddies swirl the bits. Drop a coin and make a wish. The splash
>   will echo through the blockchain for eternity, and binary fortune will
>   smile on you.

Anyone know what that means?

Comment: It's someone conjuring a clever way to have people send them Bitcoin.